# Blackberry BES transport disabled while roaming

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

according to the documentation, using the BES transport mechanism for HTTP connections will work seamlessly while roaming.

However, we have a case where the http requests are not being sent (but email on the device / browsing works fine) while roaming. Error messages include Timeouts and no response from the server (because it doesn't actually get there).

device has correct service books, active BES account, and  coverage that is providing voice and data in 3G. works when on home network...

I'm wondering if it is region specific - the test device is on Canadian carrier TELUS roaming in northern Idaho.

Anyone have experience with data requests not making it through while roaming ?

edits:
Target OS 5.0
Device happens to be a 9780
using the following type of connection code:

```
private HttpConnection getBesConnection( ) throws IOException {
    if( CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) ) {
        return getConnection( ";deviceside=false", null );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Was really just wondering if anyone had come across this problem in the development of cross-telco-network solutions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is a programming question and may not belong on Stack Overflow. However, most versions of the OS have connection debugging tools that will usually give you information on what is going on. Very difficult to be more specific without knowing what model and OS version we are discussing here.